# How to create subfolders in the Assets view?

Tags: assets, control-panel

I can't find any information on this issue, but I'm not seeing any way to create subfolders in the Assets view of the control panel. I just see all of my images with no folders. Is this feature restricted to paid versions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you see on the left in the Asset section, are asset-sources and their subfolders. You can configure them in `Settings -> Assets -> New Source`.

In this example, `Drinks` and `Cars` are asset-sources:

[image: Assets]

You can add subfolders to each asset-source (and each other subfolder) with `Rightclick -> New subfolder`.

Comment: Side note: permission to add subfolders can be restricted in the user group settings.

Comment: Sorry, not the case here as you are using the free version.

Comment: This was not so obvious - thanks for the screenshot!